# How do I capture binary output from a process different from the console output?

Tags: process, io-redirection, stdout

I'm currently able to launch a process from within Java's ProcessBuilder, which continually appends to a (binary) file output.WAV, and is continually dumping lines of console updates.  That works great - I capture the updates which tell me when it is ok to read the WAV file.

Now I'd like to skip the WAV file, and instead capture the output directly in the Java process.  Which I think can be done - I just found out that writing to `"-"` (dash) pipes the binary output to stdout.

Does that mix up the outputs?  It certainly seems to when I run it on the command line...

Comment: *"Does that mix up the outputs?"* Yes.

Comment: @MichaelHomer do you think there is any way to redirect, so "what used to be console" goes to error, and "what was used to be file" goes to the regular output?

Comment: Standard output has been commingled *within* the application here, so not externally. They are just one stream of mixed data. The application may be able to be configured to output in the way you suggest, or e.g. write to /dev/fd/3 and you read from a separate file descriptor - that depends on the details of your setup. I don't know what ProcessBuilder lets you do, or how your external process behaves, to answer.